# Postfix random mail delivery failure 554 invalid DNS PTR resource record

Tags: postfix-mta

I am getting below error randomly from one of my Redhat Postfix mail server for outbound emails.

Nemesis ESMTP Service not available 554-No SMTP service 554 invalid DNS PTR resource record).

Wondering how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the receiving system is checking your PTR record (reverse DNS entry), and either it cannot find a hostname to your IP OR the hostname it found doesn't resolve back to the same IP.